Why does this Rust package take 2x as long to build for aarch64 than it does for x86-64?
Context: At work, I am compiling a set of packages for Intel64 and ARM64, and bundling them up into Linux packages (.rpm, .deb, .apk). I'm building out a whole pipeline to enable this, which will feed into our Artifactory installation.
We're building out self-hosted, native ARM64 runners for our GitHub Enterprise Server system, to pair alongside our existing self-hosted Intel64 runners. Our runners are built atop Amazon EC2 instances. Both are compute-optimized.



CPU Arch
Instance type
vCPUs
Memory
uname -m




amd64/x86_64
c5.2xlarge
8
16 GB
x86_64


arm64/aarch64
c6g.2xlarge
8
16 GB
aarch64


arm64/aarch64
c7g.2xlarge
8
16 GB
aarch64



Hosts are EKS clusters running EKS-optimized Amazon Linux 2.
Our "runners" are K8S/EKS pods (~Docker containers) that die/re-spawn after each individual workflow. The Docker image is a multi-platform image — same software, same configuration, multiple CPUs. The container OS is Ubuntu "Focal Fossa" 20.04 LTS.
Using our self-hosted GitHub Actions runners, I wrote the GHA workflow to download the source of a Rust project and compile it — once on the Intel runner, and once on the ARM64 runner. I run uname -m and output the result as the first step in the workflow, and I see what I'm expecting. I also run file against the compiled binary, and I also see what I'm expecting.
(I'm working very hard to have an apples-to-apples comparison here.)
I'm building https://github.com/lycheeverse/lychee as a test project of the pipeline. I've not (yet) tested other compilations, but this felt complex enough to put the new ARM64 runners through the paces.
Here is the build script (${ARCH} is either x86-64 or aarch64, as appropriate):
sudo apt-get -y update
sudo apt-get -y install --no-install-recommends \
  build-essential \
  ca-certificates \
  curl \
  file \
  git \
  gpg \
  gpg-agent \
  gzip \
  libssl-dev \
  openssh-client \
  pkg-config \
  software-properties-common \
  tar \
  wget \
  ;

# Install Rust
curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sh -s -- -y
source "${HOME}/.cargo/env"

# shellcheck disable=2154
wget --header "Authorization: Bearer ${GITHUB_TOKEN}" \
    "https://github.com/lycheeverse/lychee/archive/refs/tags/v0.15.1.tar.gz"
tar zxvf "v0.15.1.tar.gz"

### Start measuring time

cd "lychee-0.15.1/" || true
cargo fetch --target="${ARCH}-unknown-linux-gnu" --locked
cargo install cargo-auditable --locked

# The `mold` linker is pre-installed.
mold -run cargo auditable build --timings --frozen --release

sudo install -Dm755 target/release/lychee -t "/usr/local/bin/"

### Stop measuring time

The Intel runner is one generation older than the Graviton/ARM64 runner. Same vCPUs, same amount of memory available. In the measured amount of time (script, above), I'm seeing these results (average of 5 builds):

Intel (c5): 6m 18s (baseline)
Graviton 2 (c6g): 12m 2s (~2x)
Graviton 3 (c7g): 9m 36s (~1.5x)

I was expecting parity between the two CPU architectures, or maybe a slight edge for ARM64 seeing that the Graviton instance is one generation newer. I also know that languages like Haskell are still working on bringing things to ARM64, and I wonder if the same is true for Rust.
For Rustaceans: are there parts of the Rust build pipeline that are not yet optimized for ARM64 on glibc-based Linuxes?
Next, I'm going to try building a significant project in Go, just to try another language that I know is optimized for ARM64, and attempt to rule-out issues with the Graviton processors. I'm also going to set up another representative Rust project to see if I get different results.

Update (same day): I performed the same test on a Go project (OpenTofu). It has over 300,000 lines of code, and also depends on several external dependencies that have to be downloaded and compiled.

Intel (c5): 3m 35s (baseline)
Graviton 3 (c7g): 2m 18s (~0.64x)

Here, arm64 was a 36% improvement over the 2-generation-old Intel instance. So I don't think my Rust issue is related to Amazon lying about Graviton price-performance. I think is has to do with something about Rust or lychee specifically.

linking can be heavy on memory, you may hit the swap if you have one.

Before this, I tested with an m6g.2xlarge instance. But the Docker-based pods/runners for CI, we have capped at 4 GB of RAM. Are you suggesting there's something about the arm64 build that requires more memory than the x86_64 build?

Also, I'm using the mold linker, which is supposed to be much faster than lld, gold, or ld.

I said "may", the logical explanation if you don't hit swap memory is just that it's slower.

To improve performance of Rust on Graviton, you should specify the use of the large-system extensions (LSE) via RUSTFLAGS before building your project. LSE is included in the Armv8.1 architecture, and improves overall system throughput. Graviton 2 and beyond, based on the Neoverse CPU line, all include the LSE feature.
Enable LSE with the following line of code before your cargo build --release command:
export RUSTFLAGS="-Ctarget-feature=+lse"

So your final code should look like this after your sudo apt-get installs:
# Install Rust
curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sh -s -- -y
source "${HOME}/.cargo/env"

# shellcheck disable=2154
wget --header "Authorization: Bearer ${GITHUB_TOKEN}" \
    "https://github.com/lycheeverse/lychee/archive/refs/tags/v0.15.1.tar.gz"
tar zxvf "v0.15.1.tar.gz"

### Start measuring time

cd "lychee-0.15.1/" || true
cargo fetch --target="${ARCH}-unknown-linux-gnu" --locked
cargo install cargo-auditable --locked

# Set RUSTFLAGS to enable LSE
export RUSTFLAGS="-Ctarget-feature=+lse"

# The `mold` linker is pre-installed.
mold -run cargo auditable build --timings --frozen --release

sudo install -Dm755 target/release/lychee -t "/usr/local/bin/"

### Stop measuring time


I ended up tracking this down in https://github.com/aws/aws-graviton-getting-started/blob/main/rust.md around the same time as you responded. But I am very appreciative of your help. Thank you! Graviton 2 was about 100% slower than the x86_64 equivalent. Graviton 3 was about 50% slower. Setting this, it's averaging around ~27% slower across 3 separate projects. The data is telling me that compilation on aarch64 is simply slower at the moment. I'm OK with that, now that I have an explanation.
